# Different product image per category in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a large store with many products showing in multiple categories.

Inside each of these categories the product has a different use, so I would like to show a different image.

I would use a bundle / grouped product however the default simple product has custom options.

Any PHP or set up suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A clean implementation would be to add a new attribute to the media/gallery functionality (akin to label/sort-order).

Then you would add a drop-down category selector to the grid view on the "Manage Product > Edit Product > Images" tab.

Then from there, you could extend the standard collection for category/search to select your image with corresponding category ID (instead of the default selected thumbnail).

But you certainly are not going to find a 1-liner to pull this off (cleanly).